# Laravel set view from helper

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a simple helper (`/app/Helpers/Helper.php`). Is is possible to set a view from helper's function? Something like `return View::make('admin.users', $page_params);`

How can I do that?

Notice: this function called in controller's `__construct`

```
public function __construct()
{
   set_view();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `setting a view? and what functionality do you expect by doing this?

Comment: @SazzadurRahman something like return View::make('admin.users',$page_params);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [view helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-view) for that.

```
return view('auth.login');
```